# React App not rendering properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, apache

Firstly - I didn't write the React code (and its my first time ever touching a React App), this is part of a group effort & im just trying to get it to run correctly on Apache.

So we're developing a React Bootstrap Web App (frontend), with PHP (backend).
Its running on a machine with Debian 8, Apache, PHP7 & Mysql.

When the page loads, it appears its not rendering any CSS.
* Note - the site is actually using SCSS not CSS.
[image]

If i look at the console error in Firefox, it shows this.
[image]

I've modified the '000-default.conf' file in \etc\apache2\sites-available to have this:

```
Alias /coaching "/var/www/coaching/"
<Directory "/var/www/coaching/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also created a .htaccess in /var/www/coaching/ which has this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Any suggestions on where the issue may be?
Is it a React issue - or is it an Apache issue?
Thanks heaps for any suggestions.

Comment: Most likely you need to add the bootstrap css to the index.html file.

Comment: The bootstrap css is already in the index.html file

Comment: are you using create react app

Comment: I'm just installing yarn, & then doing yarn build ~ its what the React developer told me to do.  (as mentioned at the start, ive never touched React before trying to deploy this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React developer found the answer to the problems we were having ~ the issue was React & their code.

Originally the dev built the frontend to use Node Server (ignoring the fact that the platform was to be running on Apache).  In making necessary changes for rendering via apache, some of the platform components were pushed to 'dev', while others were being pushed to 'production'.
Apache was only rendering components in production - which is why virtually only the header & footer were rendering (without styling), as they were the only components pushed to production.

Answer (score 0):

May be something went wrong when you setup your reactJS app. Setup basic ReactJS App.

Follow below link to setup reactJS App

**https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html**

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

After Setup ReactJS App. Then try to connect your reactJS App with PHP

**Thanks**

Comment: those instructions are based on using the Node Server to serve up React.
As I said at the start, we're using Apache to serve it.